# Select RadioGroup id and act on it when clicking a button

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm simply trying to make this page send me to another page depending on which box you check mark.

It should find the id of the box checked. Then, based on the id, it should go to a new page. However, when I click the button nothing works. I've been trying to fix this issue all night.

```
RadioGroup radiogroup;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sporgsmaltype);

    radiogroup = findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);

    Button button2 = findViewById(R.id.button2);
    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int radioid = radiogroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
            if(radioid == 0) {
                openbought();
            }
            else if(radioid == 1) {
                openbought();
            }
            else if(radioid == 2) {
                openbought();
            }
        }


    });

}


        public void openservice() {
            Intent intentservice = new Intent(this, sporgsmal1.class);
            startActivity(intentservice);
        }
        public void openrepair() {
                Intent intentrepair = new Intent(this, sporgsmal1.class);
                startActivity(intentrepair);
            }

        public void openbought() {
            Intent intentbought = new Intent(this, detaljerMain.class);
            startActivity(intentbought);
        }
```

}

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I suggest you to detail a bit the things that you have tried, that is going to help others help you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check

> radiogroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId()

radio with radio button id not with 0/1/2 cause this is not radio button id..
 you can try this

```
RadioGroup radiogroup;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_sporgsmaltype);

radiogroup = findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);

Button button2 = findViewById(R.id.button2);
button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int radioid = radiogroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
        if(radioid == findViewById(R.id.YOUR_RADIO_BUTTON).getId()) {
            openbought();
        }
        else if(radioid == findViewById(R.id.YOUR_SECOND_RADIO_BUTTON).getId()) {
            openbought();
        }
        else if(radioid == findViewById(R.id.YOUR_THIRD_RADIO_BUTTON).getId()) {
            openbought();
        }
    }


});

}


    public void openservice() {
        Intent intentservice = new Intent(this, sporgsmal1.class);
        startActivity(intentservice);
    }
    public void openrepair() {
            Intent intentrepair = new Intent(this, sporgsmal1.class);
            startActivity(intentrepair);
        }

    public void openbought() {
        Intent intentbought = new Intent(this, detaljerMain.class);
        startActivity(intentbought);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
RadioGroup radiogroup;
RadioButton serviceRadioButton,repairRadioButton,boughtRadioButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sporgsmaltype);

    radiogroup = findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
    serviceRadioButton = radiogroup.findViewById(R.id.service_id);
    repairRadioButton = radiogroup.findViewById(R.id.repair_id);
    boughtRadioButton = radiogroup.findViewById(R.id.bought_id);

    Button button2 = findViewById(R.id.button2);
    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int radioid = radiogroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
            if(radioid == R.id.service_id) {
                openservice(serviceRadioButton);
            }
            else if(radioid == R.id.repair_id) {
                openrepair(repairRadioButton);
            }
            else if(radioid == R.id.bought_id) {
                openbought(boughtRadioButton);
            }
        }


    });

}


        public void openservice() {
            Intent intentservice = new Intent(this, sporgsmal1.class);
            startActivity(intentservice);
        }
        public void openrepair() {
                Intent intentrepair = new Intent(this, sporgsmal1.class);
                startActivity(intentrepair);
            }

        public void openbought() {
            Intent intentbought = new Intent(this, detaljerMain.class);
            startActivity(intentbought);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
RadioGroup radiogroup;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sporgsmaltype);

    radiogroup = findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);

    Button button2 = findViewById( R.id.button2);
    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int radioid = radiogroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
            if(radioid ==  R.id.service_id) {
                openbought(v);
            }
            else if(radioid == R.id.repair_id) {
                openbought(v);
            }
            else if(radioid == R.id.bought_id) {
                openbought(v);
            }
        }

    });

}


public void openservice(View view) {
    Intent intentservice = new Intent( view.getContext(), sporgsmal1.class);
    startActivity(intentservice);
}
public void openrepair(View view) {
    Intent intentrepair = new Intent(view.getContext(), sporgsmal1.class);
    startActivity(intentrepair);
}

public void openbought(View view) {
    Intent intentbought = new Intent(view.getContext(), detaljerMain.class);
    startActivity(intentbought);
}
}
```

Comment: this answer came in Low Quality posts in SO.... Could you add any commentary to your answer? Explain your logic, and give a little commentary on what your code is intended to do. This will help the OP, but it will also serve as commentary for future users

Answer (score 0):

thankyou now it works using radiogroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId()